# MUI Datagrid - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Tags: reactjs, axios, material-ui, datagrid, rtk-query

Im using Material UI's datagrid to show some data in a table, I recently switched over to RTK query from redux for caching and to get rid of the global state management in the project but encountered a problem as mentioned in the title.

The error that I'm currently seeing is `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')`

This occurs when trying to get data in a nested object, I'm using `valueGetter` to get to the nested value. The const below shows the columns of the table and where `valueGetter` is being used (I've removed some of the columns for this example)

```
const columns = [
    { field: "id", headerName: "ID", width: 70 },
    {
      field: "App",
      headerName: "App",
      width: 110,
      valueGetter: (params) => params.row.app.name, // <---- Recieving error here
      valueFormatter: (params) => capitalise(params.value),
    }
  ];
```

This is what my component looks like (I've also removed some of the code just for this example):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import { IconButton } from "@material-ui/core";
import { CustomLoadingOverlay } from "../gbl/datagrid/DataGridUtils";
import { capitalise } from "../utils/util";
import {
  useGetAppAccountTypesQuery,
  useDeleteAccountTypeMutation,
} from "../../services/reducers/accounttypes";

export default ({ appid }) => {

  const { data, isLoading, isSuccess } = useGetAppAccountTypesQuery(appid);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  console.log(data, isLoading, isSuccess);
  
  // Testing only
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isSuccess) setLoading(false);
  }, [isLoading]);

  const columns = [
    { field: "id", headerName: "ID", width: 70 },
    {
      field: "App",
      headerName: "App",
      width: 110,
      valueGetter: (params) => params.row.app.name,
      valueFormatter: (params) => capitalise(params.value),
    }
  ];
  return (
    <>
      <div
        style={{
          height: 190,
          width: "100%",
          backgroundColor: "white",
          marginTop: 40,
          borderRadius: 4,
        }}
      >
        <DataGrid
          loading={loading}
          rows={data}
          columns={columns}
          components={{
            LoadingOverlay: CustomLoadingOverlay,
          }}
          hideFooter
          density="compact"
          pageSize={6}
          rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
          checkboxSelection
          disableSelectionOnClick
        ></DataGrid>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

The component re-renders a couple of times, from each render the `console.log(data, isLoading, isSuccess)` looks like

```
undefined true false <---- this gets logged 3 times
Array(2) false true
Array(2) false true
```

this issue seems to be intermittent as it does sometimes work,

Before switching to RTK query, I was using Axios and useEffect to call the endpoints and never received this error, am I doing something wrong here?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say there is nothing to do with RTK-Q itself here, it's just a common JS problem\question, that should be narrowed to null-check.
It's normal that in some conditions you may have an undefined result, and it should be treated in the code. There may be several options:

1. The most right way is to just return an empty object or loading state like spinner\skeleton, when data is undefined and\or data isLoading = true :

   const { data, isLoading, isSuccess } = useGetAppAccountTypesQuery(appid);

   if (!data || isLoading) return <>Skeleton or Spinner</>;
2. In general - use a null-safe `?` accessor:

   valueGetter: (params) => params?.row?.app?.name,
3. Set the default value for `data` with some object structure that should match your default state for proper column config:

   const DEFAULT_DATA = {
   row: {
   app: {
   name: ""
   }
   }
   }

   const { data = DEFAULT_DATA, isLoading, isSuccess } = useGetAppAccountTypesQuery(appid);
4. Just do nothing during the data loading, when data is undefined:

   const columns = data ? [...your column mapping...] : [];

You can use them in combination, achieving the expected outcome during the loading time.

Answer (score 0):

Take care of the selection model. Namely: the first time you click on a row or cell the selection model is an array with one item: the index of the selected row. If you click again on the same row the selection model is empty (the row is unselected)

```js
  selectionModel={selectionModel}
  onSelectionModelChange={(selection) => {
  const selectionSet = new Set(selectionModel);
  const result = selection.filter((s) => !selectionSet.has(s))
  setSelectionModel(result)
  if(result.length > 0)
    // save de selection model on click on a row
    setRecursoSelected(rows[result[0]])
  else
    // after clicking the same row (unselected) 
    setRecursoSelected({})
  }}
```